# Accessing functions in ViewController from different class?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I have a method called Server in my OSX app that I'm making. I am trying to design a logging console using a NSTextField that gets updated by other classes. It's throwing a Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping ...

```
class Server: NSObject {
var view: ViewController!

func output() {
    var received = "hello"
    view.sendData(received) // Throws an error here.
}
```

and in my ViewController looks pretty much,

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
@IBOutlet var consoleOut: NSTextView!
func sendData() {
      consoleOut.insertText(received!)
   }
}
```

Comment: So I initialized the server method inside my IBAction and it doesn't throw the error no more.  But it's not starting my server.      @IBAction func con(sender: AnyObject) {
        let server: Server = Server(host: "localhost", port: 9000)
        if(server.start()) {

        }
    }

Comment: I changed consoleOut.insertText(received!) to consoleOutput?.insertText(received!) and now there is no more error but nothing is outputting to my textfield.

Comment: Upon more research, it has to do with inserttext being ran in the background thread. I need to figure out how to use performSelectorOnMainThread in Swift, any ideas? Refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192252/execution-stops-on-textview-inserttext-without-exception

Answer (score 0):

You Should initialize object of class before calling its method as below.

```
class Server: NSObject {
var view: ViewController = ViewController()  // This initialization is required.

func output() {
    var received = "hello"
    view.sendData(received) // This will work now.
}
```

Comment: Can you please add console log

Comment: console is printing: (lldb)

Comment: It shows var view: ViewController = ViewController() (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address = 0x7fff5f3fffff8)

I think it has to do with init() in my ViewController, I have nothing in there for that. What should it look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `ViewController` connected in IB with a View then you must ctrl-drag that to  `Server` in order you can use it as an `@IBOutlet` (similarly to your `consoleOut`). Alternatively you can use a property which you need to set from e.g. your AppDelegate where you instantiate `Server` and have access to `ViewController`.

Comment: Dejavu, you have the same name as my Calculus 2 professor! And I was told that ViewController should be the only thing to access the textfield. It was a OOP rule, or something along those lines. (p.s this is not a homework assignment)

Also, I tried crtl + dragging stuff to server, it does nothing. Only thing it allows me to do is "bind".

Comment: You can not ctrl-drag to `server` if that is not somehow "related". You can ctrl-drag `ViewController` onto your `AppDelegate`?

Comment: I got my code to work just fine using the () now, and I took "consoleOut.insertText(received!)" out and switched it to "println(received)" and now it's not throwing anymore codes. It seems it's only throwing errors to my NSTextView.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest initializing the server object from your viewcontroller, so put

```
var server = Server(self)
```

into your viewcontroller class and implement an init with viewcontroller method in your servermodel like this one

```
init(vc:ViewController) {
 self.view = vc
}
```

one more thing: your sendData method in your vc takes no argument (sendData()) and you are calling it with a string argument.

Comment: Sorry, should have edited it better. It was just a quick example that I shortened up trying to make simple. Server is initialized in my viewcontroller. I'm getting 'ViewController -> () -> ViewController' is not convertible to 'ViewController'.

Comment: I tried putting   var server: Server = Server(host: "localhost", port: 9000, vc: ViewController.self()) instead of just 'self'. Both ways didn't work.

Comment: i assume you put the init into your NSViewController class (it has an NSView property called view), but you should have put it into the Server.

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake. I read it wrong, but it's now in my Server. I removed it, but it didn't work. Anyways, I initialized the server class inside a IBAction functioning, and it isn't giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors anymore. But it isn't starting my server either.   @IBAction func con(sender: AnyObject) {
        server = Server(host: "localhost", port: 9000)
        if(server.start()) {

        }
    }

Comment: In my debug panel, I'm getting "self VegasPanel.ViewController 0x00006000000e9b00 0x00006000000e9b00" basically saying self = server is nil, consoleout is nil.

Comment: Pretty sure it has to do with initializing my viewcontroller, trying to figure out how to add a init() function into my viewcontroller. It's being weird. I keep getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value